# Text missing from SKStoreReviewController requestReview dialog

Tags: ios, skstorereviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement StoreKit's requestReview API:

```
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
```

When the dialog comes up, it's missing the "Enjoying [app]?" and "Tap a star to rate it on the App Store" text:

[image: Title and description is missing from review dialog]

This screenshot was from an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.3.  I also was able to reproduce the problem on an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.1 as well as an iPhone 7 simulator run iOS 10.3.

I know the UI isn't exactly the same in development mode versus production, but I was under the impression that the only UI difference in development mode is that the submit button is always grayed out.

I'm hesitant to use this feature if I don't see it working correctly in development.

Any ideas how to get the title and description to appear or what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like if you swipe up over the app icon you can see the "Enjoying App?" text. It's a scroll view. Still seems weird that it looks like that in landscape mode.