# Rate app popup on iOS looks different on two different applications

Tags: ios, skstorereviewcontroller

We implemented in-app rate dialog in two our applications, however one application has cool looking view with text description but another has only icon without text. We use SKStoreReviewController to show this popup and its API has only one method (two if count deprecated) to show popup and doesn't have any customization options. Both application were launched on the same device model with same iOS version differences only in theme settings, as you could see by popup color

[image: Cool looking Rate App popup]
[image: Weird looking Rate App popup]

How it's possible to turn weird-looking popup to cool-looking with text description on it?

Comment: is your second app a non-release build?

Comment: @kbunarjo both released for a long period

Comment: is the second one landscape? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806126/text-missing-from-skstorereviewcontroller-requestreview-dialog

Comment: huh, thanks @kbunarjo from your response I realised that weird-looking app has long name and in popup it takes 4 rows instead 3 in normal app. Maybe because of this iOS decided to hide text in this way